# Is it possible to use the Facebook API to get Facepile images only?

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to use the Facebook API to get a list of Facepile images of users who like our Facebook page.

I am not looking to use the Facepile Social Plugin because it has a dictated look and feel.

Is this possible to do with the Facebook API?

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible.

Facebook doesn't have any method (either through FQL or the Graph API) that will return a list of fans for a page. Without such a method, you can't easily retrieve the ID's of fans, and thus, can't query for their profile thumbnails.

You might be tempted to "scrape" the page to retrive a list of fans. But do note, this is expressly against [Facebook's policy on the matter](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php), and may result in your page being closed or your application suspended.

"Facepile" remains the only way to list fans of a page in such a manner.